# Problems adding new notation in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to define a new notation scope and add notation to this scope in Coq. I'm following the guidance of this page in the Coq manual (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html).

I define my new scope with

```
Declare Scope myHoTT_scope.
Delimit Scope myHoTT_scope with my.
```

Later I want to add "*" as an infix operator to the scope. I do this with

```
Infix "*" := concat (at level 40 , left associativity) : myHoTT_scope.
```

where concat is an already defined function. Coq accepts all of this. It raises no errors or warning. However, if I run

```
Locate "*".
```

the only thing that is returned is the definition of "*" in type_scope and nat_scope. Additionally, if I try

```
Check (p * q)%my.
```

I just receive errors stating that p should be of type nat. I can't tell why Coq doesn't seem to pick up this new notation. I followed the instructions to the letter and Coq gives no errors.

** Edit **, I found the problem. I had the definition of the new notation tucked inside a Section so its definition was not accessible from outside the section. I guess it is not possible to define global notation from within a section?

Comment: You also need to add `: myHoTT_scope` at the end of the `Infix` notation. However it is very odd that `Locate` doesn't pick it up, but I think we need more context to be able to troubleshoot it. It would be great to have a reproducible example.

Comment: oops, That was a typo in my post. I actually have || : myHoTT_scope || in the Coq code.

Comment: The (corrected version of your) code works fine for me. Have you tested this in a new file (possibly with something other than `concat`)? If it works fine without any surrounding context, try to find the context that messes it up and share it. If it doesn't work in a new file, then tell us which version of Coq you are using and other relevant information so that we may try to reproduce it.

Comment: Thank @ana-borges I did just that and realized I had the infix line inside a section so the notation could not be located outside the section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered yourself, indeed new notations inside a section cannot be forced to be global. At least, that’s what I understand from the reference manual [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#basic-notations). And trying the `export` and `global` attributes to a notation command indeed fails.

Answer (score 1):

You never said that `*` should be in your new scope. You have to precise it in the notation declaration.

```
Declare Scope myHoTT_scope.
Delimit Scope myHoTT_scope with my.

Infix "*" := concat (at level 40 , left associativity) : myHoTT_scope.
```

Afterwards the notation is indeed found by `Locate` and is usable with the `%my` delimiter.
(Note that for me, `Locate` also finds the notation even if I don't put it in `myHoTT_scope`.)

Comment: Hey, sorry that was a typo in my post. I actually already have the code you have posted. the "myHoTT_scope" appended to the definition does not fix it.